# How to find common keys in a list of dicts and sort them by value?

Tags: python, list, sorting, dictionary

I want to create a finalDic which contains common keys and sum of their values

```
myDic = [{2:1, 3:1, 5:2}, {3:4, 6:4, 2:3}, {2:5, 3:6}, ...]
```

First find common keys

```
commonkey = [{2:1, 3:1}, {2:3, 3:4}, {2:5, 3:6}]
```

Then Sum and sort by their values

```
finalDic= {3:11, 2,9}
```

I've tried this and not even close what i want

```
import collections

myDic = [{2:1, 3:1, 5:2}, {3:4, 6:4, 2:3}, {2:5, 3:6}]

def commonKey(x):
    i=0
    allKeys = []
    while i<len(x):
        for key in x[0].keys():
            allKeys.append(key)
        i=i+1
    commonKeys = collections.Counter(allKeys)
    commonKeys = [i for i in commonKeys if commonKeys[i]>len(x)-1]
    return commonKeys

print commonKey(myDic)
```

Thanks

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Here's how I'd do it:

```
my_dict = [{2:1, 3:1, 5:2}, {3:4, 6:4, 2:3}, {2:5, 3:6}]

# Finds the common keys
common_keys = set.intersection(*map(set, my_dict))

# Makes a new dict with only those keys and sums the values into another dict
summed_dict = {key: sum(d[key] for d in my_dict) for key in common_keys}
```

Or as a crazy one-liner:

```
{k: sum(d[k] for d in my_dict) for k in reduce(set.intersection, map(set, my_dict))}
```

Comment: I would go with `summed_dict = {k:sum(d[k] for d in new_dicts) for k in common_keys}` over the `defaultdict` approach

Comment: @inspectorG4dget: Thanks. I'm not sure where I was headed there.

Comment: @Blender nice functional solution

Comment: However you can use the `set.intersection` function without `reduce`:
`set.intersection(*map(set, my_dict))` which would be faster as well

Comment: @jamylak: Thanks, I'll use that instead. I've never actually used `reduce()`, so I'm just seeing where it would work.

Comment: @Blender Everything is perfect except final result is not sorted by values.

Comment: @bekman: Dictionaries don't have an order. If you want an ordered dictionary, use this helper class from `collections`: http://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.OrderedDict

Answer (score 2):

Only some pointers:

- obtain the keys from each directory in turn them into a set() and calculate the
  intersection() or all key sets. This will give you the common keys.
- now iterating over the original data and summing up the matching values from each dict
  is straight forward

The implementation is left to the OP as an exercise.

Answer (score 1):

```
l = [{2:1, 3:1, 5:2}, {3:4, 6:4, 2:3}, {2:5, 3:6}]

new_dict = {}

def unique_key_value(a,b):
    return set(a).intersection(set(b))

def dict_sum(k, v):
    if k not in new_dict.keys():
        new_dict[k] = v
    else:
        new_dict[k] = new_dict[k] + v

for i in reduce(unique_key_value, l):
    for k in l:
        if i in k.keys():
            dict_sum(i, k[i])

print new_dict
```

hope this helps. :)

Answer (score 1):

python 3.2

```
from collections import defaultdict
c=defaultdict(list)
for i in myDic:
     for m,n in i.items():
            c[m].append(n)
new_dic={i:sum(v) for i,v in c.items()if len(v)==len(myDic)}
print(new_dic)
```