# How to go about finding the intersection of a nested list?

Tags: python, list, nested-lists

```
def query_RR(postings, qtext): 
    words = tokenize(qtext) 
    allpostings = [postings[w] for w in words]
    for a in allpostings: 
        print a.keys()
```

And this was the result of the query

```
[0, 2, 3, 4, 6] [1, 4, 5] [0, 2, 4] [4, 5]
```

The query is taking a user input term (`qtext`), tokenizing and generating a postings list for each token.

The posting list is a list of nested dictionaries.
e.g.

```
[{0 : 0.68426, 1: 0.26423}, {2: 0.6842332, 0: 0.9823}]
```

I am attempting to find the intersection for these nested dictionaries using the keys.

Can anyone provide me a solution please, would appreciate it a lot!

Comment: Have you looked at Python's built in `set` ? It provides an `intersection()` method

Comment: What exactly would the "intersection" of the two dictionaries in your example be, type-wise? What would be in it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you clarified what you wanted in a comment, here's a revised version of of the code that gathers the common values into a dictionary of lists. The trick, as others have suggested, is to use the built-in `set` type to efficiently determine the intersection of the keys.

Since my initial revision to do that, I've been able to further optimize the code using ideas in the accepted answer to a very similar question:

[How to find common keys in a list of dicts and sort them by value?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13985686/how-to-find-common-keys-in-a-list-of-dicts-and-sort-them-by-value)

Latest version:

```
def intersect_dicts(dict_list):
    """ Create dictionary containing of the keys common to all those in the list
        associated with a list of their values from each.
    """
    # Gather the values associated with the keys common to all the dicts in the list.
    common_keys = set.intersection(*map(set, dict_list))
    return {key: [d[key] for d in dict_list] for key in common_keys}


if __name__ == '__main__':
    postings_list = [{0 : 0.68426, 1: 0.26423}, {2: 0.6842332, 0: 0.9823}]
    intersection = intersect_dicts(postings_list)
    print(intersection)  # -> {0: [0.68426, 0.9823]}
```

Comment: For the common keys, how would you access the corresponding values, for my example the common value is 0 so how would you access values 0 : 0.68426, 0: 0.9823

Comment: By the way, appreciate your example above :)

Comment: Gurps: OK, that's what I needed to know. See updated answer.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback! Votes cast by those with less than 15 reputation are recorded, but do not change the publicly displayed post score. says this

Comment: Gurps: I don't think you're understanding SO's rules about this. While users with reps less than 15 can't _upvote_ answers, they can _accept_ answers to their own questions. See the help article about [Privileges](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges)

Comment: Gurps: What don't you still understand about accepting an answer?

Comment: Gurps: I see. However, it's important that you get up to speed if you want folks to answer your questions. What part of the help article was unclear? Just click on the grey checkmark next to the beginning of my answer.

Comment: oh never mind, was looking at the wrong thing. thank you